# Getting top 10 by group MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `scores` natural join users 
GROUP BY user_id,`level_id` 
order by level_id,time_to_win
```

How do i limit the results such that for each level_id it will only put top 10 (or less) in the results?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I think we could have left this question open.  I was 30 seconds away from posting what I believe could be a correct answer.

Comment: I didnt find a sufficient answer in the thread suggested. I believe there is simpler way to do what i am trying to do.

Comment: order by level_id,time_to_win LIMIT 10